# How do I print the timing of a for loop before the output of the loop?

Tags: php, microtime

I don't know if the title is correct, anyway here is what I need:

This is my code:

```
$start = microtime();
$string = $_POST['string'];
$matches = $SQL->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE ?");
$matches->execute(array('%'.$string.'%'));

echo "Done in: " . round($_GLOBALS['time'], 4);
foreach($matches->fetchAll() as $match) {
    [..]
}
$end = microtime();
$time = $end - $start;
```

As you can see, I'm measuring the time of the query + displaying records, `microtime()` needs to be at the bottom of the `foreach` but I need to display the measured time (`$time` variable) before a foreach. As you can see I've tried to do this like this: `echo "Done in: " . round($_GLOBALS['time'], 4);` but it always is returning 0 (null).

What should I do?

Comment: So far, there's no time travel in allowed in PHP.

Comment: Sorry, I really couldn't understand what you're trying to achieve. You want to display the time of the query execution before the foreach, and the time of record displaying as well after the foreach?

Comment: Why do you need to print the `Done in` statement *before* the loop?

Comment: Sense. This question makes none. You can't possibly calculate the time it takes for you to perform an action *before* you perform said action.

Comment: @JaredFarrish
Because after the loop, there'll be much table rows, and user will have to scroll down, to see execution time. Thats why I want it be to placed at the top of the page.

Comment: Then don't use `echo`'s to print directly to the output buffer. Take the results and put them into a variables (including the table), or alternatively use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), *then* output the variables/output buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
$start = microtime(true);
$string = $_POST['string'];
$matches = $SQL->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE ?");
$matches->execute(array('%'.$string.'%'));

$output = '';
foreach($matches->fetchAll() as $match) {
    $output .= $someText;
    [...]
}

$end = microtime(true);
$time = $end - $start;
echo "Done in: " . round($time, 4);
echo $output;
```

Also, note I am using the optional parameter of `true` because this returns the time as a decimal number instead of two parts as the [documentation states](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php).

Comment: What purpose does `$output = '';` serve? Also, you have a syntax error in the `Done in` line.

Comment: It allows you to buffer the output so it can be echoed later.  It seems he cares about the order.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I didn't see you using it. Yes, this is actually what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**afuzzyllama**'s answer is one way using a variable. You could also capture the `foreach` loop's [output into a buffer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php), `echo` the time, then output from the buffer:

```
$start = microtime();
$string = $_POST['string'];
$matches = $SQL->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE ?");
$matches->execute(array('%'.$string.'%'));

ob_start();
foreach($matches->fetchAll() as $match) {
    [..]
}
$table = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$end = microtime();
$time = $end - $start;
echo "Done in: " . round($GLOBALS['time'], 4);
echo $table;
```

Also, I don't know why you're using `$GLOBALS['time']` here.

Comment: `$_GLOBALS` doesn't exist. It's [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just calculate the time using microtime before the foreach too? e.g.

```
$start = microtime();
$string = $_POST['string'];
$matches = $SQL->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE ?");
$matches->execute(array('%'.$string.'%'));

echo "Done in: " . (microtime() - $start);
foreach($matches->fetchAll() as $match) {
    [..]
}
$end = microtime();
$time = $end - $start;
```

Comment: That would not give you the time it took to run the `foreach`.

Comment: Will that measure loop time also?

Comment: In its current form it will not.

Comment: I obviously misunderstood the question.  The part about wanting to display the "done in " before the foreach I thought meant @Rym wanted the SQL query time displayed prior to doing the loop, THEN a total time after the foreach loop as well at the end.